# How to compilate data from multiple sheets using query conditions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup, importrange

I'm trying to make my own Task Manager for my team. The idea is simple. I have one sheet (*Sheet A*) in that I  write tasks for my team.

[image: Here's a screen]

So, I fill just columns B, C, D. Column A is fill up automatically. In B I choose from the list one responsible for the task. Column D I set a deadline for the task.

Now, I need to import these tasks automatically in Sheets of my co-workers. I have 8 members. So, every one of them has separated Sheet with his tasks (*Sheet B, Sheet C*, etc).

[image: Here is the screen of *Sheet B* for example]

How you can see, I import data from *Sheet A* with query function. Now my co-worker needs to fill Columns E, F & G. And I need to update his responses in my *Sheet A*.

The problem is that the tasks in Sheet A are mixed and if I'll use the same query function, the responses will now correspond to tasks.

And another problem is, how to export my tasks from *Sheet A* to other sheets dependently of the name of Responsible co-worker.

So.. I understand that my questions are not simple, but I hope I'll get help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A; {
 IMPORTRANGE("ID 1"; "sheet name!A1:G");
 IMPORTRANGE("ID 2"; "sheet name!A1:G")}; 
 {5\6\7}; 0)))
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VPf06AasR4xzI5cOv0uVL6GufnYgVNI9CpUUHBQPJIQ/copy)

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the answer. So.. this is what I need but there's a moment. 
This formula works if I use sheets from the same spreadsheet. But If I made connection between sheets from different spreadsheets, the ansower didn't come in principal sheet.
Sure, I set spreadsheets & sheets ID correctly in the array formula. 
Do you have idea how to make it work?

Comment: each sheet needs to be connected to your master sheet. eg first you need to run simple importrange formula with each ID and allow access and only after all IDs are authorized this formula will work